# Cannot find yarn application logs

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

When the job finished. I can track the job history log from WebUI, but can't find the log from datanode's (which runs nodemanger service) local filesystem, nor  the logs under hdfs://user/who/.staging. I do confirm the ${yarn.nodemanger.log-dirs} is configured.

Is the yarn log deleted automatically? Or there is some services not running?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can retrieve application log using command `yarn logs -applicationId your_application_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Logs are stored in HDFS. Given the job details as below:

```
http://<host>:<port>/jobhistory/job/job_1440796954403_13743
```

Application Id:

```
application_1440796954403_13743
```

Command to fetch logs:

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_1440796954403_13743
```